WTelegramClient Retrieve Files
I can enter a Telegram channel and retrieve all messages (images, text, links), but I couldn't retrieve files. How can I do this?
foreach (var Post in History.Messages.OfType<TL.Message>().Reverse())
{
await Client.SendMessageAsync(Your.Channel, Post.message, Post.media.ToInputMedia(), entities: Post.entities);
}

